# How to make this plot.ly heatmap-esque plot in "pure" python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly

Is there an equivalent plotting function and/or a simple way to make this plot.ly plot in python in "pure" python using e.g. matplotlib?

[image]

[from here.](https://plot.ly/python/heatmaps/)

Just wondering if there is an equivalent function or similar. Cannot find any, or am not searching for the right thing. "heatmap python" only comes up with square plots, and changing their shape seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a simple example, the following will generate the attached plot.

```
from pylab import *
Z = rand(6, 100) # tried to make it look similar to your plot
c = pcolor(Z)
show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on Hun answer, if you don't want your eyes to hurt too much, you can use an alternate color map. Here `viridis`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
Z = np.random.rand(6, 100)
c = plt.pcolor(Z, cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

[image]

and remember: `pyplot` & `numpy` will keep your namespace tidy...